# Highlighting Current Category in the Archive and Feeds page

Tags: posts, categories, archives, list

I needed a category listing in my posts page and I want the current category to be highlighted. I enabled the 'All' category, so consequently, I want the 'All' also to be highlighted when I'm viewing the posts page. So I used the codex and got the following script running.

My script is:

```
<cat>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('show_option_all=All&hide_empty=0&title_li=&current_category=All'); ?>
</ul>
</cat>
```

Do I have to run an IF conditional on my archive.php file to get the category ID and highlight it using CSS class 'cat.current-cat'? How do I do it if the category is 'All' since the 'All' doesn't exactly have a category ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the function outputs the current category with a special class name by default.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Markup_and_Styling_of_Category_Lists

In your CSS you should be able to just do:

```
li.current-cat { ... }
```